# Concatenate array items

Tags: javascript

Lets say I've an Array of strings.

```
var array = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
```

Now I want to concatenate all the items of an array separated by two pipes. So the output will look like this.

```
"test1||test2||test3"
```

I have done it using `each loop` and removed the extra pipes by using `substring` method.

```js
var array = ["test1","test2","test3"]
var concantenatedString="";
array.forEach(record => concantenatedString+= "|" + record + "|");
concantenatedString = concantenatedString.substring(1, concantenatedString.length-1);
console.log(concantenatedString);
```

Which is working fine. But I'm not sure if the approach is correct, Is there any better approach to achieve this. Any hints will be really appreciated.

Comment: Just use `array.join("||")`?

Comment: @trincot gotcha, thanks..

Comment: `var array = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
console.log(array.join("||"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Array `join()` method. which is used to join the elements of an array into a string.elements of the string will be separated by a specified separator and it's default value is `comma(,)`

**Syntax:** `array.join(separator)`

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var array  = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.innerHTML = array.join(" || ");
}
```